# Элемент, "прозрачный" для мыши

Tags: html, css, javascript

Всем привет. Странный вопрос - есть ли возможность сделать элемент "невидимым" для мыши?

Поясню, есть блок `<DIV>`, в нем `<A>` с абсолютным позиционированием. `<А>` может быть больше или меньше, длиннее или шире `<DIV>`, не важно; нужно, чтобы мышь вообще не замечала этот `<A>`.

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/xNcjZ/), красные квадраты - курсор должен быть normal(и клик уходит на `<BODY>` либо то, что ниже), зеленые - pointer (и клик уходит на `<DIV>`); text'а быть вообще не должно. Итак, возможно ли и если да, то как?

*В `<DIV>` могут быть и другие элементы, "поставить прозрачную копию поверх `<A>`" рассматриваю в последнюю очередь, желательно работать только с `<A>`. Возможно JS (не jQuery)*

*PS* Ноу, ноу хакерз, нужна некликабельная метка на карту, произвольных размеров, которая может залезать на другие регионы и не накрывать их.

**UPD**: для непонимающих) Нужно сделать так, чтобы элемент (div, a - не важно) отображался, но для мыши не существовал: клики проходят насквозь, события `onmouse*` не происходят, курсор не изменяется. А в фиддле (выше) красные и зеленые квадраты - это положения мыши и реакция на них.

Теперь лучше?

**UPD** [примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ2zH/) оно должно себя вести, но без слоев `#overlay1/2`.

Comment: Вас непонятно, кое что можно решить с плохо поддерживаемым pointer-events: , но дырявых элементов не сделаешь, можно конечно геометрию всех элементов запомнить, и в js передавать событие на них. 

**говорите по русски пожалуйста** 

@Sh4dow, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @eicto, в 4 утра совсем не думается, ага?) Есть текстовое описалово, есть фиддл, есть цель (цель за меня не надо выполнять, вопрос вполне конкретен и сформулирован в заголовке и втором предложении).

Что я могу сделать сам, если неизвестно существование возможности сабжа?)

Comment: и где в вашем fiddle попытки решения, или хотя-бы указание желаемой работы ? я же говорю - простейший случай это pointer-events: none; для элементов, которые пропускать, но с зеленых на body не перейдет клик.

Comment: @eicto, "нет возможности" - тоже ответ, но я подожду еще попыток :)

Ну и повторю, я вообще без понятия, куда копать, попытки чего нужны? перебрать все css-свойства, вешать сотню событий на каждое движение мыши или что?)

Comment: Честно скажу, не понял, 1 — что надо сделать и 2 — зачем. Что вы хотите от этого получить в конечном итоге?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. "Я шо, картавый?" ©

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну что, решил сам. Спасибо, к сожалению, сказать некому)

Таки пришлось попользовать jQuery из-за ленивости перепиливания `$.trigger` и `$.css`.

[Решение (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nGU5A/)

Алгоритм примерно такой:

- вешаем на ссылку все мышиные события
- в их обработчике скрываем ссылку, получаем нижний элемент с помощью божественной функции [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.elementFromPoint) и перекидываем событие на него
- копируем в ссылку стиль курсора нижнего элемента (если он `auto` - ставим `default`)
- показываем ссылку
- обрываем событие ссылки
- профит, как говорится

Возможно, кому-то понадобится - штука весьма юзабельна на гео-картах и для разного рода всплывающих подсказок.

*ЗЫ:* если заморачиваться - курсор надо выставлять в зависимости от типа нижнего элемента - `pointer` для ссылки, `text` для текстовых полей и т.д. Но мне, честно, просто было лень, свою задачу я решил)

*Дублирую fiddle, вариант для изучения*

```js
function passEventLower(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var $el = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY));
  var c = $el.css('cursor') || 'default';
  if (c == 'auto')
    c = 'default';
  $(e.target).css('cursor', c);
  $el.trigger(e.type);
}
$('html *:not(#a1)').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(this.tagName, e.type);
});
$('#a1').on('mousedown mouseup click mousemove', function(e) {
  var $a = $(this);
  $a.hide();
  passEventLower(e);
  $a.show();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#d1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: show;
}

#a1 {
  display;
  block;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 10px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <a id="a1">some text some text some text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sh4dow, перенесите, пожалуйста, код в ответ (я бы сам это сделал, но комп в ремонте), фиддл не гарантирует сохранность фиддлов и ссылок на них.

Comment: @ReinRaus, есть

Answer (score 16):

Похожая задача разрешилась при использовании:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. 2 часа придумывал на jquery алгоритм. А решение такое простое.